# Is it possible to convert Char streams to Byte streams in Java?

Tags: java, char, byte, filestream

If it is possible to convert character streams to byte streams into a file? Would you help me explaining it by means of a program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting characters to bytes can be done with an `OutputStreamWriter` (which writes to a `FileOutputStream`) which handles translating the characters to bytes. Make sure you specify an encoding, otherwise it will use the platform default encoding and suddenly it won't work the same on all platforms anymore.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Can you please explain with a full program?

Comment: No. That would be counterproductive to you learning programming.

Comment: whether we can get input by BufferedReader?

Comment: Maybe you should be spending time with Google. I'm not going to hold your hand and teach you how to use every single class in the JDK.